# Foreach com registros do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

No meu banco de dados tenho uma tabela chamada `cadastroatendo` dentro desta tabela eu coloquei os dias de atendimento. Estou recuperando os dados através do foreach... que por sua vez a `array` retorna este resultado:

```
    [listaAtendo] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [codCadastroAtendo] => 46
                [codCadastroPerfil] => 50
                [codCadastroAtendoCat] => 7
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [codCadastroAtendo] => 47
                [codCadastroPerfil] => 50
                [codCadastroAtendoCat] => 8
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [codCadastroAtendo] => 48
                [codCadastroPerfil] => 50
                [codCadastroAtendoCat] => 9
            )

    )
```

Eu exibo os campos para estarem como "checados" caso o `codCadastroAtendoCat` for igual ao id apresentado na listagem. Listo desta forma:

Model:

```
$sql_atendo = "SELECT * FROM cadastroatendo WHERE codCadastroPerfil = {$id}";
$valor->listaAtendo = $this->db->query($sql_atendo)->result();
```

View:

```
<div class="line" style="height: 70px;">
<table style="width: 100%;">
<? 
            $contagem = 0;
            foreach($this->data['parametroAtendo'] as $valor){ 
                if($contagem==0){ 
            ?>
    <tr>
    <? } $contagem++; ?>
        <td style="300px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="atendo_codCadastroAtendoCat[]" value="<? echo $valor->idParametro; ?>" id="1_<? echo $valor->idParametro; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;<label for="1_<? echo $valor->idParametro; ?>" style="text-align: left;"><? echo $valor->parametro; ?></label>
        </td>
    <? if($contagem==4){ $contagem = 0; ?>
    </tr>
<? } } ?>
</table>
</div>
```

Preciso que: quando estiver cadastrado na tabela do banco de dados aquele ID, com aquele Perfil, o campo fique como "checado". Alguém pode me ajudar?

## Explicação:

Tenho campos do tipo checkbox, que são cadastrados previamente no banco de dados. Listo todos eles na tela, e gravo os selecionados na tabela... faço a recuperação, que vem através de um array(), porém, não consigo verificar se existe este registro no banco de dados, para colocar ele como checked, na hora de editar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que isto deve resolver.

Basicamente, a cada iteração do array `atendo` você tem de verificar se o `Id` deste elemento existe dentro do array da sua lista de atendimentos, e com isso dizer se ele vai ter a propriedade `checked` ou não.

```
<div class="line" style="height: 70px;">
<table style="width: 100%;">
<?php
            $contagem = 0;
            foreach($this->data['parametroAtendo'] as $valor){ 
                $checkado = '';
                foreach ($listaAtendo as $obj) {
                    $codCadAtendendoCat = (int)$obj->codCadastroAtendoCat;
                    if ($valor->idParametro == $codCadAtendendoCat) {
                        $checkado = ' ckecked="checked"' : '';
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if($contagem==0){ 
            ?>
    <tr>
    <? } $contagem++; ?>
        <td style="300px;">
            <input type="checkbox" name="atendo_codCadastroAtendoCat[]" value="<? echo $valor->idParametro; ?>"<?php echo $checkado?> id="1_<? echo $valor->idParametro; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;<label for="1_<? echo $valor->idParametro; ?>" style="text-align: left;"><? echo $valor->parametro; ?></label>
        </td>
    <? if($contagem==4){ $contagem = 0; ?>
    </tr>
<? } } ?>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sua resposta foi válida. Elaborei de outra forma também, que funcionou...

```
            <div class="line" style="height: 70px;">
                <table style="width: 100%;">
                <? 
                $contagem = 0;
                foreach($this->data['parametroAtendo'] as $valor){
                    if(empty($this->uri->segment(3))){ $lista = 0; } else { $lista = $this->acompanhantes_model->getByIdCategory($this->uri->segment(3), $valor->idParametro, 'cadastroatendo', 'codCadastroAtendoCat'); }
                    if($contagem==0){ 

                ?>
                    <tr>
                    <? } $contagem++; ?>
                        <td style="300px;">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="atendo_codCadastroAtendoCat[]" value="<? echo $valor->idParametro; ?>" <? if($lista>0){ echo "checked"; } ?> id="1_<? echo $valor->idParametro; ?>">&nbsp;&nbsp;<label for="1_<? echo $valor->idParametro; ?>" style="text-align: left;"><? echo $valor->parametro; ?></label>
                        </td>
                    <? if($contagem==4){ $contagem = 0; ?>
                    </tr>
                <? } } ?>
                </table>
            </div>
```